# Node AWS.S3 SDK upload timeout

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

Using the Node AWS SDK S3.upload method is not completing multi part uploads for some reason.

A readable stream that receives uploads from a browser is set as the `Body`  (the readable stream is able to be be piped to file writableStream without any problems).

S3.upload is given the following options object:

```
{
  partSize: 1024*1024*5,
  queueSize: 1
}
```

When trying to upload a ~8.5mb file, the file is completely sent from the browser, but the request returned from S3.upload continually fires 'httpUploadProgress' events that indicate that all bytes have been uploaded.  The following is received continually until the error occurs:

```
progress { loaded: 8832825,
  total: 8832825,
  part: 1,
  key: 'c82d3ef1-5d95-47df-aaa9-2cee48afd702' }
progress { loaded: 8832825,
  total: 8832825,
  part: 1,
  key: 'c82d3ef1-5d95-47df-aaa9-2cee48afd702' }
progress { loaded: 8832825,
  total: 8832825,
  part: 1,
  key: 'c82d3ef1-5d95-47df-aaa9-2cee48afd702' }

RequestTimeout: Your socket connection to the server was not read from
or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be
closed.
```

The progress loaded field shows that it has loaded the total bytes, but the upload is never completed.  Even the `end` event on the readable stream fires.

Console logging in the SDK itself shows that S3.upload consumes all the available data from the readable stream even if the part size is set to 5mb and the queue size is set to 1.

Does the part size and queue size have an impact on proper usage of S3.upload?  How can this problem be investigated further?

Comment: How can we remove the content length? Like is it at aws configuration level or from the file property?

Comment: This was actually a server time issue. The time on the server where you're running the upload from, needs to be close to the timezone of the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use createMultipartUpload and uploadPart for my larger (8Mb) file upload.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#uploadPart-property